# C# WinUI3 Application using a C++ WinUI3 Control?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime, winui

I have a WinUI3 Application written in C#.
I would like to make a WinUI3 control library (separate project/assembly) written in C++.
I would then like to use the control written in C++ inside my C# WinUI3 Application.

This does not seem to be straightforward, and I cannot find any examples of doing this.

So far, I have created the C++ library project using the 'Windows Runtime Component (WinUI 3) C++' template (in VS2022).  Is this the correct project type so far?

To that project, I have added a UserControl item, and the project builds successfully.
I can then reference the C++ project from the C# application (it appears under Dependencies->Projects in the Solution Explorer).

However, from the C# app I cannot seem to instantiate either the autogenerated 'Class' class, nor the UserControl I have added to the C++ library.

Am I missing a key step? Or am I going about this completely wrong?

(I have plenty of experience consuming C# controls from other C# projects with traditional XAML and before that, WinForms, but the changes with WinUI3 and the new terminology have me a bit confused).

(Why do I want to do this? I need to write some controls that use SwapChainPanel and DirectX, and I feel that will probably be easier and more familiar in C++ than C#.)

Comment: If you want to write a XAML control (derive from WinUI3's Microsoft.UI.Xaml), the tutorial is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/xaml-templated-controls-cppwinrt-winui-3. Other components are the same as for UWP/WinRT https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/ As for SwapChainPanel & DirectX specifics, I would definitely use full C#, it's possible with interop (WinRT/UWP/WinUI3 have nothing builtin) https://github.com/smourier/DirectN/tree/master/DirectN/DirectN.WinUI3.MinimalD3D11

Comment: Or provide a reproducible compilable sample demonstrating the issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example